# Concat the several responses of a promise into one single string

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise

The function `getDev` gets instances of the interface `DeveloperInterface`. Every instance contains the function `code` the function returns a `Promise<String>`. Now I would like to call the function for every instance and append the result to one single string and return the string.

I can output the individual result for every call of the `code` function but somehow it doesnt work to append the results to one string.

Any ideas?

```js
async function getDev(developers: Array<DeveloperInterface>) {
    try {
        var newString: string = "";
        developers.map((developer: any) => {
            developer.code().then((result: any) => {
                return new Promise(function(resolve) {
                    resolve(newString.concat(result));
                });
            });
        })
        console.log(newString);
    } catch (error) {
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: `concat` does not modify the source array in place, it returns a new array. Its' [in the manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: Thanks geoffrey! But I am using the concat method on Strings. Here the manual says it returns a new string: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/typescript/typescript_string_concat.htm

Comment: It does also return a new string, but in this case it's just concatenating the result of the `.code()` promise onto the end of `newString`, which is always `""`. You're not setting `newString` to the result of that `.concat()`, so `newString` will never actually change. On top of that, returning a `new Promise` and immediately resolving it doesn't accomplish anything there. You also end up discarding all of the promises anyways. And finally, there is no guarantee that the promises will resolve in the expected order, so even if you did set `newString`, it might not be what you expect.

Comment: Probably a better way would be to just use `Promise.all(developers.map(developer => developer.code()))`. You don't really need to make a new promise or do anything with the result of `.code()`. I'm assuming that `.code()` returns a `Promise<string>` here; if that's the case, `Promise.all()` like this would return a `Promise<string[]>` that you can just `.join("")` on the awaited result.

Comment: sorry, I mispoke. Array.concat and String.concat are essentially the same thing on different types. M. Desjardins summed up the problem and was kind enough to point out all the other problems with this code. Bottom line is you should learn Javascript

Comment: Well if I may add another problem, I don't think you should catch errors in `getDev` if the value you return is not a useful value. Promises have error management built it. Additionally, you don't need to use `try/catch` with promises. you can simply add a second param to `.then(onSuccess, onError)` or use `.catch(onError)`. You could for example return an empty string or a placeholder when a `code()` fails (if that makes sense!) or catch the whole Promise.all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some observations:

- `.map()` calls the given callback *synchronously*, and doesn't wait for any promise to resolve before making the other iterations. It returns an array.
- `developer.code().then()` returns a promise that is ignored, so there is no more way to know when all promises have resolved. Instead each promise should be returned so that `.map()` can collect those in an array for later use.
- `console.log(newString)` is executed synchronously, i.e. before **any** of the `then` callbacks has executed. By consequence, `newString` is still empty.
- If you create a new promise only to resolve it immediately, then use `Promise.resolve` instead of `new Promise`, but...:
- Returning a fulfilled promise in a `then` callback is not useful. You might as well return the value directly, because in both cases that return will resolve the promise that already exists (it was returned by the `then` method).
- `newString.concat` will not assign the result back to `newString`, so every time this `concat` is executed, it will be on the **original** value of `newString`, and the concatenation does not accumulate.
- `async` is of little use when the corresponding function does not use `await`.
- `getDev` returns a promise, but since your function doesn't return anything, it will resolve to undefined, which is not very useful for the caller of `getDev`. Instead have it return `newString`.

To make sure all pieces of the string are first collected before reporting on the result, that report on the result must also be executed asynchronously, and only when all involved promises have resolved. For this you can use `Promise.all`. If `.map()` is made to return the array of promises, you can pass that array to `Promise.all`. The additional promise that `Promise.all` creates, will only resolve when all the others have resolved, **and**, it will give as value the array of individual values that the other promises resolved with. This means you can perform the concatenation from that array.

```
async function getDev(developers: Array<DeveloperInterface>) {
    try {
        const strings = await Promise.all(developers.map((developer: any) => {
            return developer.code();
        }));
        const newString = strings.join(""); // This replaces your `concat` use
        console.log(newString);
        return newString;
    } catch (error) {
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! One question, one promise throws an error and I should concat the successfull promises with the error message. I tried to write a `catch` function for this case, but I can´t reuse `Promise.all` within the catch section because if the error gets thrown `Promise.all` gets rejected again. But I can´t either just call the `map()` function on developers, because I have to resolve the returned .. any hint on how to approach this?

Comment: @Dawienchi There is another function, [Promise.allSettled()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) that might be able to do what you want there. It resolves when all have settled, whether resolved or rejected. The return value is not the resolved values themselves but an object describing their status (whether resolved or rejected), the resolved value (for resolved promises), and the rejection reason (for rejected promises).